# Overriding --errors-only=yes specified in rcfile

Tags: python, pylint, paver

I use paver to run pylint as a task. In my rcfile(pylintrc) I have configured pylint to report only errors by setting `errors-only=yes`.

But I like to run `paver pylint` task with a verbose option to get it to report non-errors as well. How can I run pylint overriding the `errors-only=yes` setting?

Running with `--errors-only=no` gives an exception indicating that the --errors-only cannot be given a value. `--enable=all` also does not work.

Answer (score 1):

This is an unexpected restriction that deserve an issue on the pylint's tracker (https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint/issues).

Though to get it works properly in your case, I would use a custom rc file for the task that wouldn't be used in my daily usage, eg `pylint --rcfile=task.pylinrc ...`

Comment: Thanks for suggesting to use a custom rc file.